# How to store values in single dimensional character pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want store values into a character pointer pointer.I have worked out a code which is mentioned below:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int i=0,j,n,no_stops;
char *r[10],*s[10][10];
char *a,*b;


void fetch_routes_stops()
   {
   printf("Enter the no of routes:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       printf("\nEnter the route No %d:",i+1);
       scanf("%s",&a);
       r[i]=strdup(a);
   }
}

void main()
{
    fetch_routes_stops();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",r[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Pick one of C++ and C, they are different languages.

Comment: c will be preferable

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
 scanf("%s",&a);
```

is wrong, as `a` is uninitialised, and `&a` is not the argument you would need to pass. You need to allocate *enough* memory to `a` before passing that.

Better, you don't need to have a pointer for that itself. You can chnage your code like

```
  char a[128];
```

and then, use

```
  scanf("%127s", a);    //limit the input against overflow
```

to take the user input.

Or, if you *insist* to use the pointer and want to go for dynamic memory allocation, you can have a look at [malloc()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family of functions. Remember, in that case also, you pass `a` to `scanf()`, not `&a`.

After that, please note

1. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. Do not use *unnecessary* global variables. You can always pass the variables as function parameters to use them across functions.